# Compiling SASS/Compass server-side

Tags: linux, sass, compass-sass

What are my options (if any) for compiling SASS/Compass files server-side on Linux?

We have the entire codebase on Git. We use Compass/SASS for all CSS work, and I see no reason to track compiled files. We had headaches with the compiled CSS throwing merge errors since it's all on one line.

Is compiling Compass/SASS server-side a viable solution for this?

Comment: What are you using to deploy? Here is a solution with [Capistrano](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/integrating-compass-git-capistrano-deployment-workflow), I've also used git post-receive hooks successfully: http://stevegrunwell.com/blog/recompile-sass-upon-deployment-using-git-hooks

Comment: [Here is a great write up](http://jeffcroft.com/blog/2012/feb/23/many-ways-to-use-css-preprocessors/) outlining SASS/Less compilation methods, as well as some of the pros/cons of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our deploy scripts will compile the sass files to CSS and then deploy to the production servers (but of course not tracking the compiled files in git because that would cause nonsense)...

Not sure what stack you're using to deploy but it's best to compile, and then deploy instead of having every page request try to compile the files on-the-fly.